# Frank can't launch app due to "Ping failed"

Tags: ios, simulator, frank

Frank was working until last week. I have a frankified project, and now I always got:

PING FAILED!!!!!!!!!!

when the scenario come to "I launch the app".

The functional test of this project can pass in others' laptops. I checkout the project again, restart my laptop. But it also failed. And the project can run in simulator successfully.

Another thing is I try to help frank start simulator. So I start simulator before functional test run, but when it executed "I launch the app", the simulator would exit. Frank can't start simulator.....

I fight with this issue for several days, and got upset... Hope someone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I create a new iOS app, and frankified it. Then I execute : "frank launch". It only appears "LAUNCHING IN THE SIMULATOR...", but can't launch the simulator. So I thought there are something wrong in my env, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: And when I run the app by xcode, I can get response from http://localhost:37265

Answer (score 0):

In the Frank/support folder in your project's directory, there is an env.rb file that you need to edit in order to specify what simulator version you are using. Could you possibly not have a simulator version installed on your machine that the other laptops do have installed?